# I want to create an augmented reality Android app, but I lack the descriptive language to begin

Tags: android, augmented-reality

This is the gist of my app idea:

When the user turns on the app, it calculates a position 100 ft in front of them, then overlays some kind of marker onto the camera, so that when the user looks at the position through the phone, they see the marker. Then they can walk towards the marker, which gets bigger (ie "closer") as they walk towards it.

The full idea for the app is more complicated than this, but I think that if I could create this, the rest would just be iterations.

What concepts of AR, mapping, images, Android API, hardware (and anything else I haven't thought of) does this bring to mind that I need to begin learning about? I have lots of programming experience, and some Android experience but next to no AR or vision experience.

Basically, I'm hoping you guys could give me a list of terms to Google so that I can begin forming concrete ideas of how to make this.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a kind of 'Geo-Located" AR? To get search results matching what you are describing rather than methods that put the augmented content at a relative distance from the viewer, try searching "latitude", "longitude", "coordinates", "POI" etc., along with AR terms. I am currently looking into learning AWE.js because it offers true geo-located POIs (point(s) of interest) using coordinates.

I came across this (https://github.com/buildar/awe.js/issues/3) when trying to find for myself how to create geo-located POIs using AWE. For your purpose ("...calculates a position 100 ft in front of them, then overlays some kind of marker onto the camera...") you would need a way to leave the x and y axis as they are in the original 'geo_ar' demo (https://github.com/buildar/awe.js/tree/master/examples) - as relative to the user, not as lat/lon coordinates. However, for the user to be able to approach them, you would need to find a way to get them to initially appear as relative to the user (the default way), but then somehow be locked down. It normally wouldn't be necessary because in most apps geo-located POIs are placed near real physical places of some significance, so rather than the user having POIs appear near wherever he is, he goes to find them where they are. I don't know how locking down an initially-relative POI would be done - I am not a programmer, I just stalk programmers online. ;) Still, I hope that fills in some of your gaps to help you get started.

I believe there are games out there (though I haven't played them myself) that do this to spawn enemies like ghosts or zombies. They spawn a set distance away from you, but you have to run from them.